# "Random" sample from MongoDB returning heavily skewed results

Tags: mongodb, random, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I have a collection in MongoDB with ~600,000 documents. Of those, exactly half have a field set to 0, while the others have the same field set to 1. When I try to get a random sample from this collection using the [sample](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/sample/) operation in the aggregation pipeline (via PyMongo), it skews heavily toward the 1 value.

In a 25,000 record sample, there might be 300-400 records where the field is 0, and then 24,000+ records where the field in question is 1.

If the initial collection is equally distributed, why is this use of `$sample` returning results with such a vastly different distribution, and how can I get a representative sample from a collection?

Here's the PyMongo line I'm using for the query:

```
cursor = foo_database.bar_collection.aggregate( [ { "$sample": { "size": 25000} } ])
```

Comment: [`$sample`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sample/) is implemented on the server, so language implementation has no effect. There are no other argument options other than `size`, so it is very much a "black box" and just behaves as it is implemented. If you expect it to be "evenly distributed" for certain values, then you actually want "two" or more operations, being one for each value you expect to evenly distribute. Otherwise it's simply "random", just as intended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of MongoDB 3.4.9, part of the reason for the bias you've observed is that `$sample` relies almost entirely on the storage engine's random cursor implementation (see [SERVER-19183](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-19183)). This is done so that `$sample` could be performant when the collection contains a lot of data. However, since the storage engine stores documents in a sorted order using a B-tree type implementation, it's not always possible to create a truly random result.

There are currently two feature requests for better `$sample` mechanics, namely [SERVER-22069](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-22069) and [SERVER-22068](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-22068).

Having said that, if you require a truly unbiased samples of your data, rolling your own `$sample`-like solution is likely the best way to proceed at this point. Something like:

1. Get a list of all `_id` in the collection.
2. Perform a random sampling on this list (e.g. using Python's [random.choice](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.choice)).
3. Obtain all the relevant documents using the sampled `_id`, which will be reasonably performant depending on the sample size you want, since `_id` is always indexed.