# Using MongoDB aggregation $sample does not give a random result that considers the entire collection of documents

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to write a method using the MongoDB NodeJS driver that will give me a single, random document from a collection as its result.

I've seen people recommend the use of `db.collection.aggregation` and the [$sample pipeline stage](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sample/) to do this. Here is my code:

```
async findOneRandom(collection) {

    try {

      return await this.db.collection(collection).aggregate([
        { $sample: {size: 1} }
      ]).toArray();

    } catch (error) {

      console.log(error.stack);
      return null;

    }

}
```

I have a collection that has 328 documents in it. Each document has an `_id` field e.g. `{ _id: 1 }` and the IDs run sequentially from `1` to `328`.

Whilst testing this I observed that I was never seeing a result above `{ _id: 250 }`.

To investigate further, I ran the code 10,000 times and looked at the distribution of the random results. In 10,000 runs I *never* got a result with the ID `1` or any number above `251`. Here is the distribution visualised:

[image: Shows that random selection only appears considers a subset of documents]

The mongo documentation says this, but to me, that doesn't explain why the result doesn't ever contain IDs higher than 251:

> If all the following conditions are met, $sample uses a pseudo-random cursor to select documents:
>
> - $sample is the first stage of the pipeline
> - N is less than 5% of the total documents in the collection
> - The collection contains more than 100 documents
>
> If any of the above conditions are NOT met, $sample performs a collection scan followed by a random sort to select N documents. In this case, the $sample stage is subject to the sort memory restrictions.

My use case does not require a perfectly random distribution, but it appears to me as if something is wrong, or I am not fully understanding the terminology in the docs and what this pipeline can and can't do.

- Is anyone able to explain/point to documentation that explains why the $sample never appears to select from all the documents?
- Are there any changes I can make to my code e.g. supplying `options` that will address my issue? The fact that the distribution is spread across "250" documents seems very un-coincidental! I am perhaps not understanding how the mongo cursor is working (I am new and learning).

Mongo version I'm using is `4.2.6`

*Note: I am happy to consider other methods to randomly select a document, but my question is specifically about $sample as it seems like the use of $sample is the solution that is commonly recommended and I haven't yet found an article that references this issue or generally how 'pseudo-random' is implemented.*

Comment: Whilst continuing to work on this, I created a new collection where the documents were simply an integer ID e.g. `{ _id: 145 }`. The IDs ranged from `1` to `1003`. In this case my results ranged from `1` to `847`. The sample appears to return a result within the first 70-85% of the possible documents.

Answer (score 2):

After more searching I found this answer which adequately describes why the sample is not random: ["Random" sample from MongoDB returning heavily skewed results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46880603/random-sample-from-mongodb-returning-heavily-skewed-results)

> As of MongoDB 3.4.9, part of the reason for the bias you've observed is that `$sample` relies almost entirely on the storage engine's random cursor implementation (see SERVER-19183). This is done so that $sample could be performant when the collection contains a lot of data. However, since the storage engine stores documents in a sorted order using a B-tree type implementation, it's not always possible to create a truly random result.
>
> There are currently two feature requests for better $sample mechanics, namely [SERVER-22069](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-22069) and [SERVER-22068](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-22068).

[SERVER-22068](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-22068) describes how the first random sampling strategy (as described in the MongoDB documentation) is statistically biased, but the second strategy (which my code is not triggering) is statistically better distributed.

> The $sample stage currently has two algorithms to select a random sample:
>
> Using a random cursor (does a random walk over some B-tree like structure).
> A full collection scan, sorting by a random value.
> The latter strategy has a better statistical distribution, since it only relies on the random number generator, and doesn't depend on any trees being balanced. It is also better at weighting the results from shards with different amounts of data accordingly. The random walk approach has some special logic to approximate weighting per shard, but it is flawed because it only has an estimate of the number of owned documents on the shard.
>
> We should add an option to the $sample stage to force it to perform the scan + random sort approach. When this option is passed, it should probably use the better random number generator as well.

The proposal is to add an option to force the second strategy, but it has not yet been actioned, so I assume the correct approach for my use case is to use a method other than `$sample`.